# Shinydashboard Sidebar Beginner Question -- Bulletpoints

Tags: css, r, shinydashboard

My first shinydashboard app looks good so far, except for the bullet points in the sidebar. What am I doing wrong?

```
ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
    shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title="First App"),
    shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
        shinydashboard::menuItem("Accounts", tabName = "accounts", icon = shiny::icon("users")),
        shinydashboard::menuItem("Topics", icon = shiny::icon("hashtag"), 
            shinydashboard::menuSubItem("Multi-Topic-View", tabName = "topics_multi"),
            shinydashboard::menuSubItem("Single-Topic-View", tabName = "topic_single"),
            shinydashboard::menuSubItem("Tweet-View", tabName = "topic_tweet")
        )
    ),
    shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboard::tabItems(
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName="accounts", shiny::h2("Account tab content")),
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName="topics_multi", shiny::h2("Multi Topic tab content")),
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName="topic_single", shiny::h2("Single Topic tab content")),
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName="topic_tweet", shiny::h2("Tweet Topic tab content"))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

app <- shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
shiny::runApp(app, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

Here is a Screenshot when I run this code in Google Chrome on a Windows machine (R version 4.0.3, shinydashboard_0.7.1, shiny_1.6.0). Can I get rid of the bullet points?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",...)` in `dashboardSidebar()` to eliminate bullet points.  You can define your `id` as you wish.

```
ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
  shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title="First App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",  # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
    menuItem("Accounts", tabName = "accounts", icon = icon("users")),
    menuItem("Topics", icon = shiny::icon("hashtag"), 
                             menuSubItem("Multi-Topic-View", tabName = "topics_multi"),
                             menuSubItem("Single-Topic-View", tabName = "topic_single"),
                             menuSubItem("Tweet-View", tabName = "topic_tweet")
    ))
  ),
  shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="accounts", shiny::h2("Account tab content")),
      tabItem(tabName="topics_multi", shiny::h2("Multi Topic tab content")),
      tabItem(tabName="topic_single", shiny::h2("Single Topic tab content")),
      tabItem(tabName="topic_tweet", shiny::h2("Tweet Topic tab content"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]